# Sorting data pulled from one sheet to another

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to create a probe sheet for precision teaching. I have a probe input sheet and then the generate sheet.

You enter 5 words into column a on the input sheet and these are pulled into the 5x8 grid on the new sheet. Ive done this no problem but am having trouble getting the words to sort randomly in each row. The words need to be the same, just in a different order in 7 of the rows, the first row stays the same as the input.

Ive tried multiple fixes but cant seem to get the formula right. I did manage to get it to select randomly from the list but the words ended up repeated

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what a "probe sheet" is, and I am confused by the description of the resulting 5x8 grid. But If one knew the outcome that you are trying to achieve then perhaps one can help. May I suggest that you edit the question to provide a sample of 5 words, and an example of a successful 5x8 grid (you might have to create this manually).

Answer (score 0):

can you upload the sheet example? Tough to say without seeing how you want to output to look.

If you're looking to randomize a string in google sheets, you can point this formula to your list and it will randomize the output. You can then paste this into your 5x8 grid.

"=INDEX(E$3:E$8, RANDBETWEEN(1, ROWS(E$3:E$8)))"

[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPfZx.png)